# Pandas Sort Duplicate Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

How can I sort a DataFrame so that duplicate row values of a column are "added" to the row they first "appear"?
For example, my original DataFrame looks like this:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
    A  B
0  r1  0
1  r3  3
2  r3  5
3  r1  3
4  r3  6
5  r4  2
6  r2  1
7  r1  7
```

and i want to sort it the following

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
    A  B
0  r1  0
1  r1  3
2  r1  7
3  r3  3
4  r3  5
5  r3  6
6  r4  2
7  r2  7
```

I already tried `df.groupby('A')` but it didnt gave me my wanted results

Comment: `df.sort_values(['A','B'])`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary that maps column A to to an index of when it first appears, then use that to sort the df:

```
d = {}
c = 0
for i in df.itertuples():
    if i.A not in d:
        d.update({i.A: c})
        c += 1

df['m'] = df.A.map(d)
df = df.sort_values(by='m').drop('m', axis=1)

    A  B
0  r1  0
3  r1  3
7  r1  7
1  r3  3
2  r3  5
4  r3  6
5  r4  2
6  r2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by like this

```py
df.groupby("A").apply(lambda x: x[["B"]].copy()).reset_index(level=0)
```

but simple sort will work if you don't want to do some operation with the group

```py
df.sort_values("A")
## or 
df.sort_values(["A", "B"])
```